# response.redirect issue in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7, response.redirect

I am using ASP.Net + VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# + IIS 7. I am wondering if at server side, I call response.redirect to another Url in the same web application, whether session will be continued or terminated?

e.g. if I set session variable foo to value "goo" in a.aspx, then in a.aspx I call response.redirect to b.aspx, whether in b.aspx I can 100% get the value for session variable foo to be "goo"? My confusion is I heard response.redirect will not 100% continue session, is that true?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: If there are some reference documents in this scenario, it will be great.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new that will doubtless remove a bunch of bugs from my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session values are persisted through the life of the session. The session will end after the browser closes or the timeout expires, or explicitly closed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Response.redirect will always keep session variable or not?

Comment: Yes, it will it is basically just a manual way of clicking a link.

Comment: ...or the thread is aborted, which I believe to be the default behaviour of response.Redirect

Comment: I tried and seems the behavior is random, sometimes it will lost, and sometimes it will not, any ideas? BTW: I am using true parameter.

Comment: Thanks, final question, is session lost dealing with post back or no-post back? Suppose if we use Response.Redirect (with true parameter) and postback, does it works to keep session variable?

Comment: Yes, it will persist through all of .NET functionality except the three scenarios I posted above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overload for Response.Redirect that takes a `bool` as well, which does not end the response.

```
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx", false)
```

Bertrand le Roy covers it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Town. I read Roy's reply and get confused. Does it mean Response.Redirect (without specifying false parameter) will always terminates current session? And the reason is Response.End is triggered?

Comment: @George2: "_Response.End actually stops the execution of the page wherever it is using a ThreadAbortException.
What happens really here is that the session token gets lost in the battle._".  Passing `false` does not abort the thread and should conserve the session token.

Comment: So, it means using Response.Redirect to pass session variable is not safe? Is it safe to pass session variable using false parameter with Response.Redirect?

Comment: @George2: by 'pass' session variable, do you mean set a session variable, redirect and then access that session variable? That should be fine with `false`, yes.

Comment: I tried and seems the behavior is random, sometimes it will lost, and sometimes it will not, any ideas? BTW: I am using true parameter.

Comment: Thanks, final question, is session lost dealing with post back or no-post back? Suppose if we use Response.Redirect (with true parameter) and postback, does it works to keep session variable?

Comment: @George2: I'm not sure what you mean... If you set session on the first postback then redirect on the second postback, that'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Response.Redirect will kill your session and so it won't necessarily be available in `b.aspx`. Instead, try using `Response.Redirect("/b.aspx", false);` where the [false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameter makes sure that the response is not immediately killed.

Comment: "Response.Redirect will kill your session and so it won't necessarily be available" -- do you have any documents to refer to?

Comment: I tried and seems the behavior is random, sometimes it will lost, and sometimes it will not, any ideas?

Comment: The `Redirect` method calls `ThreadAbortException` as documented here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx Do you mean you've tried using the `False` parameter?

Comment: Does it mean without using false parameter, session variable will lost?

Comment: Yes, if you use false, the thread will not abruptly be aborted and your session should remain intact. I recommend reading that blog post `Town` linked to as it seems to have extra information on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, final question, is session lost dealing with post back or no-post back? Suppose if we use Response.Redirect (with true parameter) and postback, does it works to keep session variable?

Comment: A session is used to maintain information between pages and postbacks therefore it shouldn't be lost in a postback. In-proc sessions, which are default in ASP.NET, store the sessions in memory. As long as you have enough memory, they should remain between postbacks. You can also stor sessions on SQL servers if you need to scale or are handling massive amounts of information at any given time.

Comment: Just saw your edit: You shouldn't really use `True` as there's aren't many situations you need to with ASP.NET. Using it may result in losing your session because you don't know when the thread will abort.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was as follows :-

Problem: When we have moved the ASP.NET application to an another server (Windows Server 2008 R2) with IIS 7.5, the application cannot move session values between the pages. e.g. the session value was set in first page but it could not move to next page. In next page, value for same session variable was coming NULL.

Session values was moving to next page in case of Google Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

Resolution: We have created URL name with "_" (underscore)

Other Possible Solution:

1. Use Response.Redirect with having second parameter as "false" to avoid execution of page and thus to avoid lose session token. You have to use URL as follows. Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx",false)
2. If the application pool of the site is configured as a web farm or a web garden (by setting the maximum number of worker processes to more than one), and if you're not using the session service or SQL sessions, incoming requests will unpredictably go to one of the worker processes, and if it's not the one the session was created on, it's lost. The solutions to this problem is either not to use a web garden if you don't need the performance boost, or use one of the out of process session providers.

Answer (score 0):

The **Response.Redirect(url,false)** function will change the session if the **url** was **absolute url** if you dont want to loose the session use **absolute path** instead .